# Oracle JET - my oj-list-view isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-jet

I have a basic `oj-list-view` element with some static data. As far as I can see I have implemented it correctly, made sure to include all the relevant variables in the `dataSource`. Yet the element shows the loading symbol and the console simply shows an error for the `oj.Collection`. 
Where is my mistake?

**HTML**

```
<oj-list-view id="listview" aria-label="list using json data" 
           data="[[dataSource]]" selection-mode="single" drill-mode="none">
    <template slot="itemTemplate">
            <div>
              <span data-bind="text: text1"></span>
              <span data-bind="text: text2"></span>
            </div>
    </template>       
</oj-list-view>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{"text1": "cat", "text2":"meow"},
            {"text1":"dog", "text2":"woof"}];
    self.dataProvider = new oj.ArrayDataProvider(data, null );
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle Jet are you using?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` tag was introduced only in Oracle Jet version 4.1. You can try either changing your project version to 4.1 or using the  the `script` tag for the list template.

Here is the link for List Template- [Click me](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-410/jetCookbook.html?component=listView&demo=arrayListView) :)